# Flink SQL DLQ Handling

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We're trying to wrap our heads around the DLQ handling in SQL in case the de-serialization fails. As far as we've seen there are no side-output etc. using SQL. We use the kafka connector which just throws an error if it fails to de-serialize the message which causes a job stop. This stop would be OK but re-producing/ consuming all messages would take too long in certain cases and our SLA wouldn't be met.

We're using the kafka connector + exactly-once semantics + rocksdb as the state backend.
Would there be a way for example to skip an offset or do you guys use different approaches to this?

We also thought of adding a proxy before kafka so that we can't even produce wrong messages but that will take longer to be set up and used by the whole company.

We also looked into writing our own connector but that obv. has the downside of not being up to date anymore with the latest updates without manually keeping them up to date.

Comment: What format are you using?

Comment: @DavidAnderson we're using avro.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the DataStream API to handle deserialization, and then convert the resulting DataStream to a Table for further processing with SQL.

Or you could put the deserialization logic into a UDF that transforms rows of byte arrays into rows of meaningful data. However, I don't believe a UDF can use side outputs, so you might have to rely on logging or metrics to observe bad records.

Comment: The datastream to table approach and then SQL in our case I think isn't very suitable since in our case different teams define the tables/views already in SQL and we have no control over that unless we parse the SQL and then dynamically generate the tables/ views using the table API. we must provide  SQL runner that could abstract that. would there be a way to skip messages once we detect them using UDFs? I'm assuming you're reffing to something like this: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/formats/raw/